# Convolutional Neural Network with fully connected layer replaced by LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to build a neural network for baseball that can detect where the ball is and where the strike zone is when a pitch crosses the plate but my neural network appears to get stuck in a local minima where it returns the same values for every item in the dataset.

My approach is to take the 34 frames as the ball is approaching the plate and use that to detect when the ball crosses the plate.

The output is ball_left, ball_top, ball_width, strike_zone_left, strike_zone_top, strike_zone_width, strike_zone_height, frame_where_ball_crossed_plate.

My neural network model is to do convolution on every frame but instead of a fully connected layer at the end, I use an LSTM so that the neural network can infer things from previous frames.  I need to infer from previous frames because sometimes the ball will not be visible because the pitcher is in front of it or because it is in the catchers glove.

Looking at the cost over time, it appears the neural network gets stuck on a local minima and and produces the same result for every pitch in the training set.

Here is my code.

```
    filter_size1 = 5  # Convolution filters are 5 x 5 pixels.
    num_filters1 = 16  # There are 16 of these filters.

    filter_size2 = 5  # Convolution filters are 5 x 5 pixels.
    num_filters2 = 36  # There are 36 of these filters.

    filter_size3 = 5  # Convolution filters are 5 x 5 pixels.
    num_filters3 = 36  # There are 36 of these filters.

    num_hidden = 256
    lstm_layers = 2

    num_channels = 1

    num_classes = 10

    width = 320
    height = 180

    sequence_length = Directories.Pitch_Sequence_Length

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, sequence_length, width, height], name='x')

    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep_prob")

    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, width, height, num_channels])

    y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_classes], name='y_true')

    layer_conv1, weights_conv1, biases_conv1 = ConvolutionNeuralNetwork.new_conv_layer(input=x_image,
                                                                         num_input_channels=num_channels,
                                                                         filter_size=filter_size1,
                                                                         num_filters=num_filters1,
                                                                         use_pooling=True)

    layer_conv2, weights_conv2, biases_conv2 = ConvolutionNeuralNetwork.new_conv_layer(input=layer_conv1, num_input_channels=num_filters1,
                                                filter_size=filter_size2, num_filters=num_filters2,
                                                use_pooling=True)

    layer_conv3, weights_conv3, biases_conv3 = ConvolutionNeuralNetwork.new_conv_layer(input=layer_conv2, num_input_channels=num_filters2,
                                                filter_size=filter_size3, num_filters=num_filters3,
                                                use_pooling=True)

    layer_flat, num_features = ConvolutionNeuralNetwork.flatten_layer(layer_conv3)

    fc_sequence = tf.reshape(layer_flat, [-1, sequence_length, int(layer_flat.shape[1])])

    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_hidden)

    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)

    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell] * lstm_layers)

    outputs, states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(cell, tf.unstack(tf.transpose(fc_sequence, perm=[1, 0, 2])), dtype=tf.float32)

    self.y_pred = ConvolutionNeuralNetwork.new_fc_layer(outputs[-1], num_hidden, num_classes, use_relu=True)

    self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(self.y_pred - y_true, 2))

    self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4).minimize(self.cost)
```

and for the class ConvolutionNeuralNetwork.py

```
    import tensorflow as tf

    def new_weights(shape):
        return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.05))


    def new_biases(length):
        return tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.05, shape=[length]))


    def new_conv_layer(input, num_input_channels, filter_size, num_filters, use_pooling=True, weights=None, biases=None):
        shape = [filter_size, filter_size, num_input_channels, num_filters]

        if weights is None:
            weights = new_weights(shape=shape)

        if biases is None:
            biases = new_biases(length=num_filters)

        layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input=input, filter=weights, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

        layer += biases

        if use_pooling:
            layer = tf.nn.max_pool(value=layer, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

        layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)

        return layer, weights, biases

    def flatten_layer(layer):
        layer_shape = layer.get_shape()

        num_features = layer_shape[1:4].num_elements()

        layer_flat = tf.reshape(layer, [-1, num_features])

        return layer_flat, num_features


    def flatten_layer_multiple(layer1, layer2):
        layer = tf.concat([layer1, layer2], 1)
        layer_shape = layer.get_shape()

        num_features = layer_shape[1:4].num_elements()

        layer_flat = tf.reshape(layer, [-1, num_features])

        return layer_flat, num_features


    def new_fc_layer(input, num_inputs, num_outputs, use_relu=True, keep_prob=None):
        weights = new_weights(shape=[num_inputs, num_outputs])
        biases = new_biases(length=num_outputs)

        layer = tf.matmul(input, weights) + biases

        if use_relu:
            layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)
            if keep_prob is not None:
                tf.nn.dropout(layer, keep_prob)

        return layer
```

Here is what my learning curve looks like (cost over time)

[image]

and here is a sample of what the result is suppose to be.

[image]

And here is what the neural network predicts.

[image]

The neural network draws that box for the strike zone and that box for where the ball is for every pitch in the exact same location.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you really need relu on the last fc layer?

Comment: Hmm, I can try and get rid of it.  Thanks.